# Passing dataset to client side javascript from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

What I am trying to achieve is I want to pass a dataset to client side javascript from asp.net.
Please see c# code below :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sql CONN"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spuGetDetailsById", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BPId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = column2;

        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);                
        }
    }
}

var serializedDS = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), serializedDS, "Func()", true);
```

The dataset has 2 tables and I am receiving the data correctly. But when I am trying to pass it to javascript, it is showing undefined.
My js code :

```
function Func(serializedDS) {
    if (serializedDS != null)
    {
        var a = serializedDS[0]; // The table1
        var b = serializedDS[1]; // The table2
    }
}
```

Please help.

**EDIT :**

I also tried this method. It is also giving serializedDS as undefined. The Json Serialized data is showing the dataset in code though.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", string.Format("Func('{0}');", serializedDS), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `serializedDS` in your javascript method:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), 
    "getSerializedDS", 
    $"return {serializedDS};", 
    true
);
```

Later, you need to call your dynamically registered function to access the dataset in the javascript:

```
function Func() {
    var serializedDS = getSerializedDS();

    if (serializedDS != null)
    {
        var a = serializedDS[0]; // The table1
        var b = serializedDS[1]; // The table2
    }
}
```

However, there is no need to register a function just to retrieve a variable. Use [`RegisterClientScriptBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) for that purpose:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Page, 
    Page.GetType(), 
    "initMyDs", 
    $"var myDs = {serializedDS}", 
    true
);
```

Then access the `myDs` variable in your javascript as usual.

```
function Func() {
    if (myDs != null)
    {
        var a = serializedDS[0]; // The table1
        var b = serializedDS[1]; // The table2
    }
}
```

Further, [the `ScriptManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) is used ONLY for scripts, used in partial page post backs - i.e. when the registering control sits is an `UpdatePanel`. If you don't use `UpdatePanel`, do [`Page.ClientScript`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Page.GetType(), 
    "initMyDs", 
    $"var myDs = {serializedDS}", 
    true
);
```